# Create a new column based on an index column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset containing n observation and a column containing observation indices, e.g.

```
col1 col2 col3 ID
12    0    4    1
6     5    3    1
5     21   42   2
```

and want to create a new column based on my index like

```
col1 col2 col3 ID col_new
12    0    4    1   12
6     5    3    1   6
5     21   42   2   21
```

without for loops. Actually I'm doing

```
col_new <- rep(NA, length(ID))
for (i in 1:length(ID))
{
   col_new[i] <- df[i, ID[i]]
}
```

Is there a better or (`tidyverse`) way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `row/column` indexing from `base R` which should be very fast

```
df1$col_new <- df1[1:3][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$ID)]
df1$col_new
#[1] 12  6 21
```

Comment: Although I really like dplyr and purrr, I will accept this answer because the intent of the code is much clearer.

Answer (score 5):

For a possible `tidyverse` approach, how about using `dplyr::mutate` combined with `purrr::map2_int`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mutate(df, new_col = map2_int(row_number(), ID, ~ df[.x, .y]))
#>   col1 col2 col3 ID new_col
#> 1   12    0    4  1      12
#> 2    6    5    3  1       6
#> 3    5   21   42  2      21
```

**Data**

```r
df <- read.table(text = "col1 col2 col3 ID
12    0    4    1
6     5    3    1
5     21   42   2", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Really nice. I have to admit that I tried hard with dplyr but wasn't aware of map2_int.

Comment: There is `row_number()` which you can use instead of `1:n()`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, good suggestion. I've edited to include `row_number()` - I think that it makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
# Using OPs data
setDT(df)
df[, col_new := get(paste0("col", ID)), 1:nrow(df)]

# df
   col1 col2 col3 ID col_new
1:   12    0    4  1      12
2:    6    5    3  1       6
3:    5   21   42  2      21
```

Explanation:

- For each row: `1:nrow(df)`
- Get corresponding column using `ID`: `get(paste0("col", ID))`
- Write this value into a new column: `col_new :=`

Answer (score 1):

Another tidyverse approach, this time that uses only `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
    gather(column, col_new, -ID)  %>%  
    filter(paste0('col', ID) == column) %>%
    select(col_new) %>%
    cbind(df, .)
```

It's longer than @markdly's elegant one-liner but if you're like me and get confused by `purrr` most of the time, this might read easier.