# Create a new column based on an index column with error

Tags: r, indexing, cbind

I am referring to a previous question:-
[Create a new column based on an index column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884901/create-a-new-column-based-on-an-index-column?rq=1)

I've tried few conversions to convert into tibble but still hitting the following error:

```
> Can't use matrix or array for column indexing
```

[Need to create the NewCol based on the colnumber in SecondLast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9q6E.png)

Here the sample data:-

```
structure(list(L1;L2;L3;L4;L5;L6;L7;L8;L9;L10;SecondLast;NewCol = c("10001;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;1;10001", 
"10005;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;1;10005", "10006;10001;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;2;10001", 
"10007;10003;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;2;10003", "10008;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;1;10008", 
"10009;10004;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;2;10009", "10021;10005;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;2;10005", 
"10022;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;1;10022", "10023;10055;10182;10201;10164;10088;10049;10027;10022;1;9;10022", 
"10024;10004;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;2;10004", "10025;10055;10182;10201;10164;10088;10049;10027;10022;1;9;10022", 
"10030;10010;10003;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;3;10003", "10031;10043;10056;10020;10003;1;NA;NA;NA;NA;5;10003"
)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), spec = structure(list(cols = list(`L1;L2;L3;L4;L5;L6;L7;L8;L9;L10;SecondLast;NewCol` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

This is the code I used:

`df$Leader <- df [1:30][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$SecondLast)]`

How to convert the data type into the right class?

Comment: Please format you question and make it easier on eyes.

Comment: Noted...I try harder next time...thanks

Comment: You may want to share your sample data using `dput(head(df))`

Comment: Getting better....thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally....

The initial class for my `table` is 
 `"tbl_df"  "tbl" "data.frame"`

I did a `as.data.frame` conversion to 
`"data.frame"`

Thanks guys